# App icon is not show in running app but its showing in launcher in android

Tags: java, android

I face this problem first and could not able to sort it I need a help of you guys for solving the problem for better understandings picture is also attach

fori mazdoor icon is blank in running app
[image: fori mazdoor icon is blank in running app]

fori mazdoori icon is showing launcher icon
[image: fori mazdoori icon is showing launcher icon]

my android manifest is now my icon is not showing and my icon also placed in drawable folder sorry for weak english please help me in finding a solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.forimazdoori.Fmuserapps"
    android:versionCode="14"
    android:versionName="2.1.4">

    <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="14"
       android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
          android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" 
    />

    <!-- Declaration for writing/reading on SD card -->
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Declaration for camera access -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to 
     use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or 
     fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"

    android:authorities=
    "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider759142140921307"
        android:exported="true" />


    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
       />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="false" />


    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SearchResultActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WorkerProfileActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"


    android:configChanges=
    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UserProfileActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoViewActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FavoritesActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CommentsActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string 
    resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to 
    sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, 
    including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in 
    src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterAsWorkerActivity" />

    <service
        android:name=".utils.SyncProvider"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".AddFriendActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ValidatePhoneActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name=".PendingReviewActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PremiumActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_premium"
        android:parentActivityName=".SearchActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.forimazdoori.Fmuserapps.SearchActivity" 
        />
       </activity>
       </application>

       </manifest>
```

Comment: Have you added launcher icon with all dimensions? like xhdpi, xxhdpi,mdpi etc

Comment: To answer you as to why you need different dimensions, read this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

**From the Android Developer  Guide**

Almost every application should have alternative drawable resources for different screen densities, because almost every application has a launcher icon and that icon should look good on all screen densities. Likewise, if you include other bitmap drawables in your application (such as for menu icons or other graphics in your application), you should provide alternative versions or each one, for different densities.

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:

- 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
- 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
- 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
- 96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
- 144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
- 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density